# Is $1 \over \sqrt n$ $\lt$ $1 \over \sqrt N$ in this solution because they are fractions?

Tags: calculus

The formal definition of a limit says requires a convergent sequence to have $n \geq N$ but for example, when trying to prove that the limit of $1 \over \sqrt n$, how come my textbook gives the example:

Let $\epsilon$ = $1 \over 100$. How big does our cutoff N have to be so that if $n \geq N$, then $1 \over \sqrt n$ < $1 \over 100$ whenever $n \geq N$?
For this statement to hold, we would need 10000 < n.
So let's choose any cutoff $N \epsilon \Bbb N$, so that N > 10000. In particular N = 10001 would work. Then if $n \geq N$ we would have 
$1 \over \sqrt n$ < $1 \over N$ < $1 \over \sqrt (10000)$ = $1 \over 100$.

So is the only reason why they say $1 \over \sqrt n$ < $1 \over N$ because it has the "1 over"? If the sequence was just a plain $\sqrt n$ instead, would it have $N \lt n$ in the proof instead?

Answer (score 1):

So, if you had the sequence $\sqrt{n}$ it wouldn't converge so there would be no choice of $N$ for any $\varepsilon$. In your case, we choose $n \geq N$ which is equivalent to saying $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Taking the square root doesn't change anything.